# Cambiar por ruta amigable con Htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

me pueden guiar para poder realizar una url amigable de la siguiente dirección:

https://test.ejemplo.cl/educacion/cursos/curso?t=1&s=0&c=51&v=1&n=aplicacion-de-tecnicas-de-instalaciones

y que quede de la siguiente manera:

https://test.ejemplo.cl/educacion/cursos/curso/1/0/51/1/aplicacion-de-tecnicas-de-instalaciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La regla quedaria de la siguiente manera

**Url entrada:**

```
https://test.ejemplo.cl/educacion/cursos/curso/1/0/51/1/aplicacion-de-tecnicas-de-instalaciones
```

**Regla**

```html
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteRule ^educacion/cursos/curso/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)/?    /educacion/cursos/curso.php?t=$1&s=$2&c=$3&v=$4&n=$5
```

**Url salida**

```
https://test.ejemplo.cl/educacion/cursos/curso.php?t=1&s=0&c=51&v=1&n=aplicacion-de-tecnicas-de-instalaciones
```

puedes comprobar en

https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=fef5d82a-0aa8-43c7-86db-ed14b079dc4c